# How can we attach an effective event handler to a rich:select with enableManualInput="true"?

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces

My requirement is:

1. We need to trigger the event after typing a value in the input field
   of the `<rich:select>`
2. There is condition that the typing values are not in  select
   list(rich select `userLoginBean.userList`) but it is in backingbean
   Entity object but not displaying in rich select.

I just want to pass the value which is typed in rich:select in backing bean, so that it can check and validate value in Entity bean,
so far I achieved this,

```
<rich:select id="user"
             value="#{userLoginBean.user}"
             required="true"
             listWidth="385px"
             enableManualInput="true"
             defaultLabel="Please Enter">

    <f:selectItems value="#{userLoginBean.userList}"
                   var="c"
                   itemValue="#{c.userid}"
                   itemLabel="#{not empty c.name? c.name.concat(','):c.name}#{not empty c.alias? c.alias.concat(','):c.alias}#{c.userid}"/>

    <a4j:ajax event="keyup" oncomplete="if (event.keyCode == 13) {callToJs((#{rich:component('user')}.getValue())); }" />
    <a4j:jsFunction name="callToJs"  actionListener="#{userLoginBean.searchUserList}" >
        <a4j:param name="value" assignTo="#{bean.searchValue}" />
    </a4j:jsFunction>
</rich:select>
```

But the JavaScript function `callToJs()` doesn't get values in backing bean code:

```
<a4j:ajax event="keyup"
          oncomplete="if (event.keyCode == 13) {callToJs((#{rich:component('user')}.getValue())); }"/>
```

Comment: Why not just merge the two lists?

Answer (score 0):

In richfaces 4.x you can do something like this instead:

```
<rich:hotKey key="enter" onkeydown="callToJs(#{rich:jQuery('user')}.val());"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code:

- `a4j:ajax` is for making ajax requests in response to client-side event, if you just want to execute some JavaScript you can use the on* attributes of the parent component
- `event.keyCode` will not work in "oncomplete" since that doesn't receive the `keyup` event
- `a4j:jsFunction` needs to be defined outside the <rich:select>, it can't be a child element
- `select.getValue()` returns the selected option, `getLabel()` returns the typed string

so the correct way is:

```
<rich:select id="user"
         value="#{userLoginBean.user}"
         required="true"
         listWidth="385px"
         enableManualInput="true"
         defaultLabel="Please Enter"
         onkeyup="if (event.keyCode == 13) {callToJs((#{rich:component('user')}.getLabel())); }">

…

</rich:select>
<a4j:jsFunction name="callToJs"  actionListener="#{userLoginBean.searchUserList}" >
    <a4j:param name="value" assignTo="#{bean.searchValue}" />
</a4j:jsFunction>
```

But I think merging the two lists would be a better solution.

Comment: Merging the list might cause problem to search a word on typing in the list ,still I have to pass the typed value(search value) to backing bean  in order search and if found then reload the userlist. Can you please show a sample code